# Is there a way to customise the bootmenu UI for NOOBS

Tags: multiboot

I want to customise the bootmenu shown with my Raspbian + Kodi setup. I have not found any reliable guides how to do this.

Using Rpi3B with Noobs

Comment: https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/blob/master/README.md you should be able to muck about with ../os/os.json to do what you want.

Comment: I do not see how this makes a custom UI possible?

Comment: Then it probably isn't without hacking the code and creating your own version of NOOBS. Personally I just swap an SDCard or a USB stick if I want some other OS to boot.